# Computing an array of values for each meshgrid point

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that depends on some parameters and which output is an array. For example:

```
def my_func(xs,param1,param2,param3):
    values = xs**param1 + xs*param2**2 + param3*xs
    return values
```

where xs is an array with values. Suposse I also have a list of values for each of the parameters:

```
xs = np.arange(0,10,1)
params1 = np.arange(5,10,1)
params2 = np.arange(1,30,1)
params3 = np.arange(1,20,1)
```

I would like to compute the output of my_func for each possible combination of params1, params2, and params3. The idea is to be able to compute chi squares and perform bayesian analysis with the output.
I know it can be done with nested for loops, but I was wondering if that could be done with mehsgrid. I tried the following, but it breaks:

```
P1, P2, P3 = np.meshgrid(params1,params2,params3)
results = my_func(xs,P1,P2,P3)

      1 def my_func(xs,param1,param2,param3):
----> 2     values = xs**param1 + xs*param2**2 + param3*xs
      3 
      4 
      5 xs = np.arange(0,10,0.1)

      ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (10,10,40)
```

Any idea of how this can be done (if it can be done)?

**Edit:**
The answer by @unutbu works, but no I have one extra question regarding the format of its output. I have changed the parameters ranges so it can be easily explained.

After passing `xs` as a parameter for `np.meshgrid`, the shape of `results` is

```
np.shape(results)
(5, 10, 29, 19)
```

Meaning that:
axis0 is `param1`,
axis1 is `xs`,
axis2 is `param2`, and
axis3 is `param3`.

Why is `xs` put in axis=1 in the output? I would expect the order to follow what passed to `np.mesgrid`, i.e., `xs,param1,param2, param3`.

**Edit2:**

sorry, I have just discovered the "indexing" keyworkd for np.meshgrid. In case anyone needs the indexing as I was planning to use it, use `np.meshgrig(arguments,indexing='ij')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `xs` also as an argument to `np.meshgrid`:

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(xs,param1,param2,param3):
    values = xs**param1 + xs*param2**2 + param3*xs
    return values

xs = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
params1 = np.arange(1,2,0.1)
params2 = np.arange(1,2,0.1)
params3 = np.arange(1,5,0.1)

X, P1, P2, P3 = np.meshgrid(xs, params1, params2, params3, sparse=True, indexing='ij')
my_func(X, P1, P2, P3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that works :) Now, I have an extra question regarding the format of the output. I've edited my question to explain it.